# How to pass props to component through pseudo element - 'component'?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

Is there a way to pass props to component through pseudo element 'component'?

Example:

```
<component :is="ChildComponent">
```

How to pass parameters to ChildComponent?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like you would for any other component.

```
<component :prop="myProp" :is="ChildComponent">
```